# How to apply style to a specific element in JQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning the basics of JQuery, and can't solve this problem: given 3 green `<li>` elements turn 1-st and 3-rd elements to red color, and the 2-nd element to orange.

#### Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>element</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      ul li{color: green;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>text 1</li>
      <li>text 2</li>
      <li>text 3</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      var lis = $("ul li").css("color", "red");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was able to make all the elements red, but I can't make the 2-nd orange: `lis[1].css("color", "orange");` doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$(element)\[index\].addClass(); does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314884/elementindex-addclass-does-not-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling css on DOM object instead of jQuery object as indexer `[]` gives you DOM object You need [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of indexer

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3P7J/)**

```
lis.eq(1).css("color", "orange");
```

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the
>   specified index.

You can also use [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) directly in the selector

```
$("ul li:eq(1)").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it with pure CSS by applying `:nth-child` selector:

```
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2UF5w/)**

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning `jQuery`, you can use the [`:even` selector](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/):

```
var lis = $('ul li');
lis.filter(':even').css('color', 'red'); // Zero based indexing selects 0 and 2
lis.filter(':odd').css('color', 'orange'); // Selects 1
```

Note, from the docs:

> Because :even is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :even cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :even to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":even").

Answer (score 1):

please write your code in **[document.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)**  and use **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

**for all element**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("ul li").css("color", "red");
    });
```

**for particluar element**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li:eq(0)").css("color", "red"); //for first element
    $("ul li:eq(1)").css("color", "red");//for second element
    $("ul li:eq(2)").css("color", "red");//for third element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only first element than use this...

use CSS pesudo selector :first-of-type

$("li:first-of-type").css("color","orange");

or you can use jQuery built in selector

$("li:first").css("color","orange");

Both will work fine...but the jQuery method is relatively slower than CSS pesudo selector
so use the first one for better performance

now if you want to select any other index then use .eq()

$(selectorName.eq(index)).css(...);