# $(element)[index].addClass(); does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple element with the same class. When I use this method below, it does not work.

```
$(".tab-content")[index].addClass("active-content");
```

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="tag">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    Lodon
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    Paris
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    Tokyo
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <h3>Lodon</h3>
            <p>London is the capital of England</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <h3>Paris</h3>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <h3>Tokyo</h3>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS

```
$(".tag li").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(".tab-content")[index].addClass("active-content");
});
```

https://codepen.io/WillyIsCoding/pen/KoMxMJ

Comment: Okay a lot of people already have the solution but here is what your problem is: You are trying to call a method on a HTMLCollection which consists of Nodes. You cannot select the Node from an array contect as you want to call a jQuery Method so you need such an object that uses jQuery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because `.addClass()` is a jQuery-method, not a native JS-method.

And when you use `$(".tab-content")[index]`, you are selecting the true DOM-element within the jQuery-object. The same kind of element you get when you use `document.getElementById("id")`.

And just like when you would combine that with a jQuery-method:
`document.getElementById("id").addClass("class");`
this too will generate an error and not work:
`$(".tab-content")[index].addClass("class");`

In order to get this working, you have to stick with jQuery. Luckily, jQuery has a method to do just that: [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/). Just like `.addClass()`, this is a jQuery-method so you can use it in the same manner.

---

**SOLUTION:** `$(".tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active-content");`

This method will select the element at the given index of the complete set of matching elements, and only perform the action on that one element.

---

After a bit of fiddling around, I came up with this alternative implementation of your code.
I thought I'd put it on here, maybe someone will find it useful:

```js
$(".select").change(function() {
  $(".tab.active").removeClass("active").addClass("hidden");
  $(".tab").eq($(this).children("option:selected").index()).removeClass("hidden").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.tab.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select class="select">
    <option selected="selected">London</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>Tokyo</option>
  </select>
  <div class="tab active"><h3>London</h3><p>London is the capital of England</p></div>
  <div class="tab hidden"><h3>Paris</h3><p>Paris is the capital of France</p></div>
  <div class="tab hidden"><h3>Tokyo</h3><p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan</p></div>
</div>
```

*jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdea7mc8/*

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. After reading your explanation and do some research, that is what I understand, $(".class") will return a jQuery objects list, $(".class")[index] will return the same with document.getElementByClassName(class)[index] which is a true Dom-element. But jQuery methods like addClass() can only work with jQuery objects, so when I combined them, they will be incorrect syntax. Do I understand correctly? @myfunckyside

Comment: @Willy yes that is correct, if you open DevTools (F12) you will also get an error that confirms this: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[index].addClass is not a function**, because the compiler is now looking for a native JS method/function to go along with the native DOM element. And then it comes across `addClass`, which it does not recognize as a valid (native) method/function, because it's jQuery.

Comment: I got it! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

A small change might help you

```
$(".tag li").click(function () {
            var index = $(this).index();
            $(".tab-content").eq(index).addClass("active-content");
 });
```

Comment: Try eq function

Comment: eq() is the solution, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one

```
 $(".tag li").click(function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
       $(".tab-content").removeClass("active-content");
       $($(".tab-content")[index]).addClass("active-content"); 
});
```

In addition to adding active class to your tab content, make sure we remove active class on the remaining.(again its based on our requirement)

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution.

First you need to access the element

```
var el = $('.tab-element')[index];
```

And then assign the class

```
$( el ).addClass("any-class");
```

That's work for me.

This is a small version:

```
$( $('.tab-element')[index] ).addClass("any-class");
```